# Are the both "In the Data Base" and "On the Data Base" correct?| ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

I run into the following statement when I was reading a book about **Learning ASP.NET Core API**:

> We reference “CommandItems” **on** our DB Context (_context) and  return
> as a List of Command objects.

A complete explanation shown below:

[image]

And here is some explanations of the picture added above:

> 1. Class constructor utilizing the injection of or DB Context.
> 2. We reference “CommandItems” **on** our DB Context (_context) and  **return** as a List of Command objects.
> 3. We call the FirstOrDefault method on our “CommandItems” to  return a Command object (if one exists) that matches our desired ID.

I now have two questions about number 2:

> 2. We reference “CommandItems” **on** our DB Context (_context) and  **return** as a List of Command objects.

1- Is it "**on** our DB Context" or "**in** our DB Context"? Are the both true?

2- What do we return when saying:

> and  **return** as a List of Command objects?

Have anything omitted after the the term "return"? (i.g. return them as..., or return CommandItems as...)

Answer (score -2):

1. You can understand that your database `Command Database` (DbContext) has the table with name `CommandItems`
2. A database table should have multiple records, that why returning a List of objects corresponding to those records.